# Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ with unusual generating set

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Polya's recursion theorem says that a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ is recurrent. In the proofs that I have seen, one considers the steps to be of lengths $+1$ and $-1$. My question is the following: Is this also true changing the generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$?

For example, the set $\{6,10,15\}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$ and no subset of it does. Consider the random walk that takes steps of length $6$, $-6$, $10$, $-10$, $15$, $-15$ uniformly. Is this random walk recurrent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach to the recurrence/transience of random walks on lattices uses *discrete Fourier transform*. More specifically, one first notes that, for every integer valued random variable $S_n$, $$2\pi P(S_n=0)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi E(e^{itS_n})dt$$ and that, when $(S_n)$ is a random walk starting from $0$ with steps distributed as $X$, $$E(e^{itS_n})=\left(E(e^{itX})\right)^n$$ These two remarks put together yield the key formula

> $$2\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n=0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(E(e^{itX})\right)^ndt=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{dt}{1-E(e^{itX})}$$

Now, if $X$ is symmetric with $p_x=P(X=x)$ for every $x$, then $$E(e^{itX})=p_0+2\sum_{x\geqslant1}p_x\cos(tx)$$ hence $$1-E(e^{itX})=2\sum_{x\geqslant1}p_x(1-\cos(tx))$$The convergence of the integral $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{dt}{1-E(e^{itX})}$$ depends on the behaviour of the function near $0$. When, as here, the support of $X$ is bounded, the expansion up to order $x^2$ is always valid, and yields the equivalent $$1-E(e^{itX})=2\sum_{x\geqslant1}p_x\left(\frac12t^2x^2+o(t^2)\right)\sim vt^2$$ when $t\to0$, with $$v=\sum_{x\geqslant1}p_xx^2=\frac12E(X^2)$$ In particular, the integral diverges at $t=0$, thus the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n=0)$$ diverges, thus the random series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{S_n=0}$$ is infinite almost surely (can you prove this step?), that is, the random walk $(S_n)$ is recurrent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be recurrent as well (it is not important that the step lengths form a generating set, as long as they are symmetric with respect to the origin). Hint: Loosely speaking, you can split your walk in three classical walks, which just consider steps of one absolute step size. Each walk is recurrent, by Polya's theorem, hence for each there are arbitraryly large times at which they are positive and negative. How can you deduce from that, that there are "times", such that ALL three are positive (and negative) at the same "time" (depending on how you write it down the three walks won't be entirely independent, but in some sense that is enough here). It is hard to write down properly, but the idea should be clear(?).

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you are saying but I am having trouble understanding why this works. Polya's theorem also says that walks on $\mathbb{Z}^3$ are not recurrent. We can also "split up" these walks into 3 walks, one for each coordinate. Why doesn't your argument it work in this case?

Comment: It is the geometry of $\mathbb{Z}^3$: There will also be times, where all three walks are positive respectively negative each, but that does not mean that you passed through the origin "in between". There is simply too much "space", you walk around the origin. In your case above, you have to walk through the origin by the "line structure" of $\mathbb{Z}$ (in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ the proof does not work as well with the same reason, even if in this case the walk is recurrent..).

Comment: Sorry but "the idea" is not at all "clear". Since nobody proves recurrence this way, can you be more specific (the "in some sense" parenthesis being disquieting in this context)?

Comment: Why do you have to go through the origin? Consider the following sequence of values that are added to the RW: (6,10,15,-15,-15,-10,-10,-6,-6). The three split up random walks you are describing are all positive at some point and are all negative at another and the walk never goes through the origin.

Comment: Oh you are right, I am sorry. This is not an answer at all (to the moderators: shall I delete it?). I will think about it in more detail.

Comment: I agree it will not work this way, sorry. I am not even sure if it is true anymore.

Comment: Don't delete your answer, I think it helps understand the problem. Unless you want to.